# Breakpoint not hitting

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I ported an application from VC6 to VS 2008. I rebuilt the application in release build.  The Pdb file is available in the folder where exe is located.  But when I loaded the application and put break point I am getting the following message

*"The breakpoint will not currently be hit.No symbols have been loaded for this document"*

What would be the cause of the issue?

Comment: Just use __asm int 13; to trigger a breakpoint from code ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The debugger could not find either the application or the PDBs.

When you start the program, exactly which binaries are loaded are shown in the Output window.  Make sure the right files are being loaded.  When everything loads properly, the output looks something like this:

> 'hacks_vs10.exe': Loaded
>   'C:\Users\john\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\hacks_vs10\x64\Debug\hacks_vs10.exe',
>   Symbols loaded.

When the PDB is not found, instead of saying "Symbols loaded" it says:

> Cannot find or open the PDB file

Make sure that you are first running the correct version of your application (check the running path), and then make sure that the PDB is in that directory. You can change where the PDB is generated to by tweaking "Project>Properties...>Linker>Generate Program Database File"

Comment: I am getting the message 'HoTSim2.0.exe': Loaded 'D:\Projects\AsWorxSim\Bin\Release\HoTSim2.0.exe', Symbols loaded. Still The break points are not hit

Answer (score 1):

The debugger could not find code associated with the source location you put the breakpoint at.

There can be a number of reasons for this. The one I've most often found was a section of code that was truly not compiled in. (either because of preprocessor conditionals or dead-code removal).

I imagine there can be other reasons too (e.g. inlining, though in theory, the compiler could generate the proper mapping for all the inlines. I don't know what VS2008 does here).

Are you sure you're putting the breakpoint in a code path that is supposed to be executed ?

Comment: The debugger can cope with inlining just fine, in my experience.

Comment: @DeadMG: I'm pretty sure I had issues in the past in some cases. But a simple test works. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

The PDB file you mention is probably not related to the release build,

Debug information is normally absent in the release build (though you can enable it if you have to but should anticipate surprising effects due to compiler optimizations).

Therefore, you can only set breakpoints on known DLL entry points (possible via the Module List view - it has been a while since I used Visual Studio intensively) or directly on assembly instructions.

Note that you could perhaps compile part of your application with debug symbols.

Comment: In VC2008, debug information is generated by default unless you turn it off.

Comment: The pdb file is generated as part of exe and no compiler optimizations are enabled. What should I do now?

Comment: @John Dibling: It wasn't enabled in the version ported from VC 6.0. So I enabled it.

Answer (score 0):

I have just solved a similar problem

- I re-referenced all my DLL's
- went to (Tools->Options, "Projects and Solutions", "Build and Run") and set "On Run when projects are out of date" to 'Prompt to build'

I'm not sure which of these fixed the problem, but it did!